# Fill List<object> in a new thread and get it back to the UI Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I got following function generating a List of LinesVisual3D objects. I need to do this in a new task, because it's very time consuming.

```
public async Task<List<LinesVisual3D>> Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync(IProgress<int> prog = null)
    {
        var list = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate ()
            {
                var temp = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (List<GCodeCommand> commands in Model.Commands)
                {
                    var line = drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false);
                    /*
                    if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                        DispatcherObject.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list.Add(drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false))));

                    */
                    temp.Add(drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false));

                    if (prog != null)
                    {
                        float test = (((float)i / Model.Commands.Count) * 100f);
                        if (i < Model.Commands.Count - 1)
                            prog.Report(Convert.ToInt32(test));
                        else
                            prog.Report(100);
                    }
                    i++;
                }

                list = new List<LinesVisual3D>(temp);
            });
            LayerModelGenerated = true;
            return list;

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

[image]

It actually works fine, however I do not get the list out of the background thread. When I access the list in the UI (different thread), I'll get this result:

[image]

I know that the problem is, that the list was filled / generated in a different thread (in this case, ThreadId = 3). However the UI is running in ThreadId = 1

I already tried to invoke directly after the loop has finished.

```
//DispatcherObject = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                    DispatcherObject.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list = new List<LinesVisual3D>(temp)));
                else
                    list = new List<LinesVisual3D>(temp);
```

I also tried to invoke while adding to the list.

```
if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                        DispatcherObject.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => list.Add(drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false))));
```

The result always was the same.

**EDIT1:**
Tried with single instance instead of list.

```
public async Task<LinesVisual3D> Create2dGcodeLayerAsync(IProgress<int> prog = null)
    {
        var temp = new LinesVisual3D();
        try
        {

            await Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate ()
            {
                if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                    DispatcherObject.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => temp = drawLayer(3, 0, Model.Commands[3].Count, false)));
                //temp = drawLayer(3, 0, Model.Commands[3].Count, false);
            });
            LayerModelGenerated = true;
            return temp;

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return temp;
        }
    }
```

This seems to work. I guess becuase the `temp` object is generated outside the new task, however the object `line` in the task?

**EDIT2:**
This function works, however freezes the UI...

```
public async Task<List<LinesVisual3D>> Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync(IProgress<int> prog = null)
    {
        var list = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
        var line = new LinesVisual3D();
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate ()
            {
                var temp = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (List<GCodeCommand> commands in Model.Commands)
                {
                    // Freezes the UI...
                    if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                    {
                        DispatcherObject.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            line = drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false);
                            list.Add(line);
                        }));
                    }

                    if (prog != null)
                    {
                        float test = (((float)i / Model.Commands.Count) * 100f);
                        if (i < Model.Commands.Count - 1)
                            prog.Report(Convert.ToInt32(test));
                        else
                            prog.Report(100);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            });
            LayerModelGenerated = true;
            return list;

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Either it works and freezes the UI, or it leaves the list in the old thread and doesn't freeze the UI :(

**Solution:**

Instead of creating the `LinesVisual3D` object in the loop, I just create a List of `Point3D` and create a new `LinesVisual3D` at the `Invoke`.

```
public async Task<List<LinesVisual3D>> Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync(IProgress<int> prog = null)
    {
        var list = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
        var line = new LinesVisual3D();
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate () 
            {
                var temp = new List<LinesVisual3D>();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (List<GCodeCommand> commands in Model.Commands)
                {
                    var pointsPerLayer = getLayerPointsCollection(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false);
                    if (DispatcherObject.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
                    {
                        DispatcherObject.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            line = new LinesVisual3D() { Points = new Point3DCollection(pointsPerLayer)};
                            list.Add(line);
                        }));
                    }

                    if (prog != null)
                    {
                        float test = (((float)i / Model.Commands.Count) * 100f);
                        if (i < Model.Commands.Count - 1)
                            prog.Report(Convert.ToInt32(test));
                        else
                            prog.Report(100);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            });
            LayerModelGenerated = true;
            return list;

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Points:

```
private List<Point3D> getLayerPointsCollection(int layerNumber, int fromProgress, int toProgress, bool isNextLayer)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: what if you create just one instance of the LinesVisual3D on a background thread, will it be broken either? something like public Task<LinesVisual3D> CreateLinesVisual3DInstanceAsync() {... }

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. When I just create one instance and Invoke the creation, then it works. See edited question above.

Comment: I think that the creation of the LinesVisual3D instance needs to be done on the UI thread (maybe also accessing its properties), then filling the list can be done on background thread. I also noticed you are using the BeginInvoke which runs asynchronusly..

Comment: Yes, I did use `BeginInvoke` because `Invoke` is freezing the UI... I just updated my function, now it works, however freezes the UI... Please see the edited post above.

Comment: maybe you will need to run another UI thread, see [here](https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/)

Comment: What exception have you got when accessing those properties?

Comment: Hi, got the `InvalidOperationException`. I already fixed it, you can find the solution at the original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not get the list out of the background thread. When I access the list in the UI (different thread), I'll get this result:

You get *the list* out of the background thread, what causes problems is *accessing the properties of the individual list items.*

Most likely, those items are ui objects themselves and have to be created on the ui thread. So you have to dispatch each `new` back to the ui thread, which essentially leaves adding them to the list as only job for the background task, which will hardly be cpu-bound, so just drop the background thread.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that hint. I must have been blind... I solved it by just generating a list of `Point3D`, instead of the `LinesVisual3D`. Then I create the `new LinesVisual3D` from the points list. Works perfectly. I edit the question above with the final code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

at a guess I'd say the initial call to Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync returns the first empty instance of list, when the inner thread starts it also creates a new instance of list in fact two new instances as the last line initialises a new instance with temp, the population of these instances are never returned from Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync.

try replace

```
 temp.Add(drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false));
```

with

```
list.Add(drawLayer(i, 0, Model.Commands[i].Count, false));
```

and delete

```
list = new List<LinesVisual3D>(temp);
```

As the call to Create2dGcodeLayerModelListAsync is async (await ..) it will spin up a worker thread anyway the inner thread is redundant and waists time spinning up yet another thread. but start by getting rid of the news first.